# Uploading file to dropbox using Dropbox's v2 API

Tags: php, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to save an uploaded file in Dropbox using PHP and also use Dropbox's v2 API for this.

I'm not getting any response for this.

Below is my code.

```
  <?php
$filename = 'qw.txt';

$api_url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload'; //dropbox api url
        $token = '<REDACTED>'; // oauth token

        $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.
            json_encode(
                array(
                    "path"=> '/'. basename($filename),
                    "mode" => "add",
                    "autorename" => true,
                    "mute" => false
                )
            )

        );

        $ch = curl_init($api_url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        $path = $filename;


        $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
        $filesize = filesize($path);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

        $response = curl_exec($ch);


        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        echo($response.'<br/>');
        echo($http_code.'<br/>');

        curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting below response.

[image]

Comment: This code looks and works fine for me. What do you mean when you say you don't get any response? You should get some sort of HTTP response from the Dropbox API, or an error if it was unreachable for some reason. Perhaps try inspecting `$response` before your call to `curl_getinfo` in case it was an error.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for your reply 
I am getting a blank page as a result also attached a screenshot

Comment: Have you tried inspecting `$response` directly?

Comment: @Greg This code is worked 
When I test this code in live server my image is upload on dropbox and I     get response 
This error occurred when I test this code on localhost

Comment: Please check `$response` before the call to `curl_getinfo`. That would be a good next step for debugging this.

Comment: @greg Thanks for your reply This problem is solved and I get correct response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you get access token from Dropbox app run below code your file will uploaded on dropbox

```
 <?php
$filename = 'pr.jpg';

$api_url = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload'; //dropbox api url
        $token = 'Generated access token'; // oauth token

        $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer '. $token,
            'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
            'Dropbox-API-Arg: '.
            json_encode(
                array(
                    "path"=> '/'. basename($filename),
                    "mode" => "add",
                    "autorename" => true,
                    "mute" => false
                )
            )

        );

        $ch = curl_init($api_url);

       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        $path = $filename;


        $fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
        $filesize = filesize($path);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); // debug

        $response = curl_exec($ch);


        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);



        echo($response.'<br/>');
        echo($http_code.'<br/>');

        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: {"error_summary": "missing_scope/..", "error": {".tag": "missing_scope", "required_scope": "files.content.write"}}